# ckeditor plugin for MathML rendering

Tags: ckeditor

I need to drop a MathML formula into the CKEditor window and have it render it visually for the user. Creating an image file would be ideal.  From CKEditor  I see the following plugins:
[mathjax](http://ckeditor.com/addon/mathjax) -- but this only works with TeX, not MathML.

also there is:
[eqneditor](http://ckeditor.com/addon/eqneditor) -- it is an editor, but it only supports LaTeX.

all suggestions and ideas welcome. Thanks.

Comment: How aboot a conversion: http://www.w3.org/Math/Software/desc/desc_Itranslator_from_mathml_to_tex_latex.html

Comment: thanks for the reply.  That does sound tempting, however that link you provided is an online translator from what I could see.  The translator would need to be a part of the code and not an online service.  Even still, I would consider that as a last resort.  I am considering diving into creating a plugin.